# Why exim send/not send emails from different users on server via php?

Tags: php, apache, freebsd, exim

The server has 2 users: admin and joe. Both users belong to same groups.
If I try to send email from domains (via php script) which belong to admin - everything works. But for domains which belong to joe - function `mail()` does not send email.

I enable `mail.log` in `php.ini` and saw that php is working correctly.

Apache/2.4.16 (FreeBSD) mpm-itk/2.4.7-02

exim 4.86

`/usr/local/etc/exim/passwd` - empty

`mainlog, paniclog` - doesn't have errors

Result `exim -bd -d+all`:

```
WHITELIST_D_MACROS unset
TRUSTED_CONFIG_LIST unset
12:54:37  8586 changed uid/gid: forcing real = effective
12:54:37  8586   uid=0 gid=0 pid=8586
12:54:37  8586   auxiliary group list: 0
12:54:37  8586 seeking password data for user "www": cache not available
12:54:37  8586 getpwnam() succeeded uid=80 gid=80
12:54:37  8586 seeking password data for user "mailnull": cache not available
12:54:37  8586 getpwnam() succeeded uid=26 gid=26
12:54:37  8586 seeking password data for user "root": cache not available
12:54:37  8586 getpwnam() succeeded uid=0 gid=0
12:54:37  8587 changed uid/gid: calling tls_validate_require_cipher
12:54:37  8587   uid=26 gid=6 pid=8587
12:54:37  8587   auxiliary group list: 6
12:54:37  8586 tls_validate_require_cipher child 8587 ended: status=0x0
12:54:37  8586 configuration file is /usr/local/etc/exim/configure
12:54:37  8586 log selectors = 0000cffe 00733801
12:54:37  8586 cwd=/etc 3 args: exim -bd -d+all
12:54:37  8586 trusted user
12:54:37  8586 admin user
12:54:37  8586 DSN: dnslookup propagating DSN
12:54:37  8586 DSN: disabled_domains propagating DSN
12:54:37  8586 DSN: disabled_users propagating DSN
12:54:37  8586 DSN: local_domains propagating DSN
12:54:37  8586 DSN: group_aliases propagating DSN
12:54:37  8586 DSN: aliases propagating DSN
12:54:37  8586 DSN: aliases_pipe propagating DSN
12:54:37  8586 DSN: local_users propagating DSN
12:54:37  8586 DSN: catchall_for_domains propagating DSN
12:54:37  8586 DSN: unknown_users propagating DSN
12:54:37  8586 DSN: autoreplay propagating DSN
12:54:37  8586 DSN: localuser propagating DSN
12:54:37  8586 DSN: a_dnslookup propagating DSN
12:54:37  8586 DSN: a_disabled_domains propagating DSN
12:54:37  8586 DSN: a_disabled_users propagating DSN
12:54:37  8586 DSN: a_local_domains propagating DSN
12:54:37  8586 DSN: a_aliases propagating DSN
12:54:37  8586 DSN: a_aliases_pipe propagating DSN
12:54:37  8586 DSN: a_local_users propagating DSN
12:54:37  8586 DSN: a_catchall_for_domains propagating DSN
12:54:37  8586 originator: uid=0 gid=0 login=root name=Charlie Root
12:54:37  8586 LOG: MAIN
12:54:37  8586   IPv6 socket creation failed: Protocol not supported
12:54:37  8586 LOG: MAIN
12:54:37  8586   Failed to create IPv6 socket for wildcard listening (Protocol not supported): will use IPv4
12:54:37  8586 LOG: MAIN
12:54:37  8586   socket bind() to port 25 for address (any IPv4) failed: Address already in use: waiting 30s before trying again (9 more tries)
```

Answer (score 1):

By default all users except `exim_user` and `exim_group` are untrusted so they can't send messages from other users. Therefore when exim is invoked by `php` it is forced to use sender_address like `www@host` - because user `www` used to launch apache/nginx that invoke php that invoke exim.

You have to add `www` user to the exim's `trusted_users` or `trusted_groups`. The other approach is to use SMTP session instead of direct exim invocation. Just configure your PHP to use real IP where your exim is listening for connection and that's enough.

Comment: This anything does not explain why php send emails from admin and dont send from joe.
trusted_users is already www. I trying to change trusted_users and trusted_groups but without result.